# How to Allow Protected Cells to Be Formatted and Adjusted in Size - VBA

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, cell

I have set up a locked workbook where I have locked the sheets using VBA. How do I adjust this code to allow the user to change row/column height and format cells (that is, change the cell format to percentage instead of currency, for example). The sheet should remain locked however. This is the code I have so far in Workbook_Open:

Many thanks in advance :)

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim wSheet As Worksheet

Sheet1.Protect Password:="12345", _
        UserInterFaceOnly:=True

Sheet11.Protect Password:="12345", _
        UserInterFaceOnly:=True

Exit Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`Worksheet.Protect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.protect) documentation has what you need, specifically the following parameters, which should all be `True`.

> - `AllowFormattingCells`: **True** allows the user to format any cell on a protected worksheet. The default value is **False**.
> - `AllowFormattingColumns`: **True** allows the user to format any column on a protected worksheet. The default value is **False**.
> - `AllowFormattingRows`: **True** allows the user to format any row on a protected. The default value is **False**.

Answer (score 0):

The arguments for [Worksheet.Protect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.protect) include options for *AllowFormattingCells* and *AllowFormattingRows*.

AllowFormattingRows covers the ability to change row height. AllowFormattingCells covers most standard cell formatting but does not cover everything; e.g. indenting is not allowed.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Sheet1.UnProtect Password:="12345"
    Sheet1.Protect Password:="12345", _
                   UserInterFaceOnly:=True, _
                   AllowFormattingCells:=True, _
                   AllowFormattingRows:=True

    Sheet11.UnProtect Password:="12345"
    Sheet11.Protect Password:="12345", _
                    UserInterFaceOnly:=True, _
                    AllowFormattingCells:=True, _
                    AllowFormattingRows:=True


End Sub
```

A sub procedure should terminate in *End Sub* not *Exit Sub*.

Comment: Don't you need `AllowFormattingColumns` as well though, assuming the ability to change column width is also desired? (at least column was originally mentioned, my interpretation of "*row/column height*", as well as the question title).

Comment: My bad; I reread the question and it was *change row/column height* not *change row height*. I guess the *height* without *width* threw me.